# How to get user friends list?

Tags: facebook

How can I get the user friends list of the logged in user? I authenticate the user and request the permission using the server redirect approach, for example:

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + "client_id=" + "12345678" + "&redirect_uri=" + "https://www.myserver.com:44316/FaceBookLoginRedirect.aspx" + "&scope=user_status,email,user_friends" + "&response_type=token");
```

---

FB doesn't show the user the permission request dialog and doesn't return the data such as email and user_friends

any idea?

Thx

Comment: encode you url using `encode(url)`

Comment: this works without encoding, it's just a redirect to facebook auth. The   problem is that after in comes back it doesn't have the friends list although it has the email correctly.

Comment: even when i encode the url, it' works the same???

Comment: What programming language are you using?